# Separate mobile CSS sheet vs. separate mobile page?

Tags: css, mobile

I'm trying to find out if it will be a better use of my time (now and in the long-run) to make a separate style sheet for my mobile site (which will look drastically different, but use the same database information and elements), **or** , make a whole new mobile page and *steal* what I need from my desktop site.

Does anyone have an advise or know what most developers practice when it comes to mobile sites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use media queries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" />
```

Or in css3

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Thanks. How accurate is the media tag in picking up mobile browsers? Do most modern devices recognize this, or do I still need to redirect using PHP for devices that do not?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of sites these days are concentrating on mobile first, then porting to a full web app for desktops. More and more peyote are using their mobiles to browse the web and  a site designed for mobile will generally support desktops better than a desktop site will support mobile browsers.

I read about device.is at HTML5 rocks here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/cross-device/

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of controversy in that. I personally prefer media queries. and it they aren't TOO complex, I put them right in my css file using `@media FOO and ( max-size: ### ) { /*stuff*/ }`

A "mobile website" usually like m.domain.com, is usually a very stripped down version. containing some products, info, and a way to contact.

Why would you hide the rest of your valuable site info just because someone is on a smaller device? the load time can be a bit longer since there is more content, just make sure you super important stuff is above the fold. (or at least higher up in the draw order)

You can also very easily include click to call and click for map buttons that appear at a certain size using media queries.